# pyomo ipopt on colaboratory (colab.research.google.com)

Tags: pyomo, ipopt

I was happy to find out that pyomo was already pre-installed on colaboratory .
Unfortunately, the solver I need is not installed.
I tried to install it, but it did work.
(using  conda install ipopt_bin -c cachemeorg)

Any idea how to install ipop  on colaboratory  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this installation command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge ipopt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
!apt install coinor-libipopt-dev
```

And then this:

```
!pip install ipopt
```